# Operating on data table based off of multiple row and column conditions

Tags: r, data.table, subset

Say I have the following data table:

```
prc = c(2,5,4,6,7,3)
ret = c(0.01,0.03,-0.02,0.01,-0.001,0.04)
cap = c(100,200,300,80,40,900)
comp = c("a","a","a","b","b","c")
dt = data.table(comp, prc, ret, cap)

   comp prc    ret cap
1:    a   2  0.010 100
2:    a   5  0.030 200
3:    a   4 -0.020 300
4:    b   6  0.010  80
5:    b   7 -0.001  40
6:    c   3  0.040 900
```

I want to operate based off of the following conditions: For each company, at row t, there must be a prc at row (t - 2), ret at row (t - 1), and cap at (t-2). Therefore, the only row in which I would be operating on is 3.

I have tried this:

```
> dt[, which(is.na(shift(prc,2)) | is.na(shift(ret,1)) | is.na(shift(v,2))), by = comp]
   comp V1
1:    a  1
2:    a  2
3:    b  1
4:    b  2
5:    c  1
```

As anticipated, the only row not included is the row in which comp = a and prc = 4. Now what could I do to to make a mathematical operation on that row. Note that I do not want to delete the rest of the rows because they will be used in the calculation for the desired row.

Comment: Based on your description, it is a bit unclear what you expect as solution.

Answer (score 1):

May be this helps

```
dt[dt[, .I[seq_len(.N)>=3], comp]$V1]
#   comp prc   ret cap
#1:    a   4 -0.02 300
```

If the intention is not to subset, but to have to new column, say 'Flag' that show TRUE/FALSE values

```
dt[,  Flag := seq_len(.N)>=3, comp]
```

Answer (score 0):

The OP already was on the right track but stopped halfways.

```
dt[, which(is.na(shift(prc, 2)) | is.na(shift(ret, 1)) | is.na(shift(cap, 2))), by = comp]
#   comp V1
#1:    a  1
#2:    a  2
#3:    b  1
#4:    b  2
#5:    c  1
```

selects all rows within each group which do **not** fulfill the requirements. (Note that in the original code the OP referenced `v` which isn't present in the data set).

By negating,

```
dt[, which(!(is.na(shift(prc, 2)) | is.na(shift(ret, 1)) | is.na(shift(cap, 2)))), by = comp]
#   comp V1
#1:    a  3
```

selects all rows within each group which fulfill the requirements.

```
dt[, .SD[!is.na(shift(prc, 2)) & !is.na(shift(ret, 1)) & !is.na(shift(cap, 2))], by = comp]
#   comp prc   ret cap
#1:    a   4 -0.02 300
```

returns all rows of the original data.table which fulfill the condition including all columns.

Note that (a) Boolean algebra has been used to replace the condition `!(A | B | C)` by `!A & !B & !C` and (b) the call to `which()` has been made redundant.

---

[The solution of akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43796660/3817004) can be streamlined in a similar way. Instead of

```
dt[dt[, .I[seq_len(.N)>=3], comp]$V1]
```

we can write

```
dt[, .SD[seq_len(.N) >= 3L], comp]
```

Note that both approaches *are **not** fully equivalent*. While the latter approach simply shows all rows for each `comp` which have at least two preceeding rows, the first approach additionally checks also the contents for `NA` which I believe is more reliable.